# Word for redesigning historic items inspired by modern items

Tags: expressions

I know of the word Anachronism, which is for an item to be present in a different time period.

I have just watch Robin Hood (2018). In this film the writers/producers have taken inspiration from some modern items for the design of their weapons and clothing.

For example:

1. The Sheriff's men use crossbows that are short, black, have a 'magazine' of bolts on the top and are fast firing with auto reload. The aesthetic is very close to an FN P90 sub machine gun.
2. Whilst some lords are dressed in what I would call the "classic Henry the 8th" look, Robin and the Sheriff appear to wear clothes closer to a 3 piece suit.
3. In the beginning of the film the squad of English archers use tactics that wouldn't go amiss in a modern day Close Quarters Combat and use Bows closer to full Rifles/Carbines and the overall battle feels like it has been shot to replicate a set piece out of a COD game.

All these changes are clearly inspired by modern items/practices but are not full blown Anachronisms as they are not the actual item.

Is there a word for writers/directors re-designing historic things by taking inspiration from modern items?

Edit:
Here is an image that I have managed to grab from a trailer. I will try and get some more tonight.

Whilst the weapon from point 1 is shown, all black with a short stock and top loading magazine, you can also see the guards armour has similar look and feel to modern body armour design.

[image]

Comment: They exercise their poetic license.

Comment: *Anachronism* seems fitting. Setting high-tech bows in a period of history that didn't have them is anachronistic. You might also call it *futuristic*, depending on what sentence/paragraph you use the word in.

Comment: When I can get home I can take a screen shot from Netflix and upload a clearer photo. They are not high-tech bows that have "fallen through time", as they are still clearly wooden.

Comment: The [repeating crossbow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_crossbow) isn't in the wrong time but the wrong place, as it was invented in China around 2000 years ago. So it is an [**anatopism**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatopism).

Comment: I'm just not describing the technology, more like the look, feel and impression that the item gives. It essentially made me say "That's what an FN P90 would look like if it was a crossbow".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but maybe this could work -

## Retrofuturism

(adjective *retrofuturistic* or *retrofuture*)

> : the use of a style or aesthetic considered futuristic in an earlier
> era.

(From [Lexico](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/retrofuturism))

(You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrofuturism).)

Comment: Mitch is closer to what I am looking for. Its not that the item is clearly futuristic, like if made a car today was made to look like the Jetsons space car, it would still look out of place today/clearly not be of this era. The items have been adapted more suitably with key nods to the modern item.